# Acces a TreeView Form inside GridView to populate ComboBox collection

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, combobox, treeview

I have a following problem with Windows Form Application. I have two forms: CategoryTree.cs form with TreeView inside and a ProjectForm.cs with DataGridView inside. I would like to populate DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Collection with TreeView nodes text e.g. I have tree which looks like this:

```
Science Fiction 
   Movie1
   Movie2 
Horror 
   Movie1
   Movie2
Action
   Movie1
   Movie2
```

and so on. I want those categories to be Items in the ComboBoxColumn. My code looks as follows in the CategoryTree form

```
public partial class CategoryTree : Form
{
   //adding nodes to the tree
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      TreeNode newone = new TreeNode();
      newone.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
      newone.NodeFont = new Font(catTreeView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
      newone.Text = nameBox.Text;
      catTreeView.Nodes.Add(newone);

      //and code for adding child and grandchild and ...

   }
   //other stuff 
}
```

In the DataGridView I have the following method

```
public void AddComboBox()
    {
        int i;
        CategoryTree cat_Form = new CategoryTree();
        //Set the cat_Form Active
        cat_Form = ActiveForm as CategoryTree;
        if (cat_Form != null)
        {
            i = cat_Form.catTreeView.Nodes.Count;  //here i get exception
            if(i != 0)
            {
                var newone2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                newone2.HeaderText = "Main category";
                newone2.Name = "ColNr_" + nofCols;
                string comboTxt;

                for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                comboTxt = catTreeView.Nodes[j].Text;
                newone2.Items.Add(comboTxt);
                }

                mainProjectGrid.Columns.Add(newone2);
                nofCols += 1;
            }

        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this code generates 'System.NullReferenceException'. The catTreeView modifier is set to 'public'. I had many different approaches to the problem, but none of them worked.

As you may see my questoin is - how can I get to the catTreeView object from the ProjectForm form and populate combobox?

I'm absolute beginner so answers with example code will be always appreciated.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!
__Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes  __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! -

Comment: Yes it's Windows Form Application. DataGridView! I will remember now. I tried to be as specific and precise as I could.

Answer (score 0):

To Whom It May Concern. I found the solution to this problem. In TreeView I added one button programed this way

```
private void applyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProjectForm newProject1 = new ProjectForm( catTreeView );
    newProject1.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    newProject1.Text = "blabla";
    newProject1.Show();
}
```

Next I added this to the ProjectForm.cs

```
public ProjectForm(TreeView catView)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    holalala = catView;
}

public void AddComboBox()
{
    int i;
    if (holalala != null)
    {
        i = holalala.Nodes.Count;
        if (i != 0)
        {
            var newone2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            newone2.HeaderText = "Main category";
            newone2.Name = "ColNr_" + nofCols;
            string comboTxt;

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                comboTxt = holalala.Nodes[j].Text;
                newone2.Items.Add(comboTxt);
            }

            mainProjectGrid.Columns.Add(newone2);
            nofCols += 1;
        }
     }
}
```

This solution is pretty simple and works fine. I think I can now add few lines to not just add Columns but also to update them with new Nodes that may appear in the TreeView.  I will work on that later :).